# Write CSV file column title in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, javascript-objects, export-to-csv

This is my code. I am trying to output my data as CSV and I am being successful but I can't add the title of the columns. Although I saved the CSV file but the column titles are missing. Can anyone help in this?

```
var d= new Date();
var t=d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds();
var data = dataAWS
var result = data.map(function(val) {
    return t+'","'+val.payload.test_data;
}).join('"\n"');
var csvData = '"'+ result +'"';

var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("tempN.csv", csvData, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while saving CSV.");
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("CSV file has been saved.");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more I would suggest something like:

```
data.unshift(column_headers);
var result = data.map(function(val) {
    return t+'","'+val.payload.test_data;
}).join("\n")
etc, etc
```

Comment: I had done that. It will just make two columns without title. So, I found a better way. I created a CSV file with two columns first, and then used append to put the column values.